# How is a pitch between a C and a C# notated in sheet music for fretless instruments?

Tags: notation, instruments, string-instruments, note-bending, pitch

Suppose we have a violin or a contrabass, they can play midnote pitches. I guess there must be a way of notating that in classical sheet music,llll how?

I realise that it is a small chance it could ever be used anywhere but still.

Concerning 12 note sheet music:
What about guitar bends that can be halfway, quaterway down or up? How are vocal pitches notated?

Comment: That seems to be several questions at once, all with different potential answers. There are several systems for notating pitches outside of 12-tone equal temperament, and some are used exclusively for some instruments (guitar being a good example). Note that no guitar bends are ever down, it's not possible to bend down.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Ah, good old Ben, son of Mr. and Mrs. Down... There is, however, a strangely named 'pre-bend'.

Answer (score 6):

I googled "How to notate microtones" (I've been wondering too) and found this. It's on a flute website, but it should work for all musical purposes.

http://www.flutecolors.com/techniques/microtones-quartertones/

Basically, there are certain accidentals that you can use for quarter tones and micro tones, which apparently does happen.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtonal_music) also explains, and here's an image of some of the wacky accidentals:

[image]

So for a pitch between `C` and `C#`, you could write `"C1/4#"` (third on the image, except for `A` instead of `C`)

Comment: Good catch. As I mention in my comment, this is only one of several systems for notating microtonality, but it is a good example.

Comment: Wow, i have indeed seen such notation a few times. Never wondered what those numbers meant. I can see the Sharp and Flat signs differ, that's so much to learn for microtonality.

Comment: For once, tab works well! 1/4 with an arrow speaks volumes, but is somewhat lacking on a proper stave, not that the weird signs were ever used much. I can't even access them on my qwerty board.

Comment: There are several more systems two examples above. Explore sections 4.18 to 4.38 of https://w3c.github.io/smufl/gitbook/ for a recent attempt at producing a comprehensive "standard" set of music notation symbols.

Comment: Also see here http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation-big-page.en.html#accidentals (look for "Quarter tones")